# Add Custom Attribute To Recently Viewed Products Widget

Tags: magento2, xml, uicomponent, knockoutjs, widget

I have override widget_recently_viewed.xml in my theme in Magento_Catalog
with

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="widget_columns">
        <column name="brand" component="MyVendor_MyModule/js/product/brand" sortOrder="2" displayArea="details-area">
            <settings>
                <label translate="true">Brand</label>
                <bodyTmpl>MyVendor_MyModule/product/brand</bodyTmpl>
            </settings>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
proj/app/MyVendor_MyModule/product/brand.html
```

proj/app/code/MyVendor/Product/view/base/web/js/product/brand.js

```js
<!-- get it from Magento_Catalog/js/product/name -->

define([
    'Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column',
    'Magento_Catalog/js/product/list/column-status-validator'
], function (Column, columnStatusValidator) {
    'use strict';

    return Column.extend({
        /**
         * Depends on this option, product name can be shown or hide. Depends on  backend configuration
         *
         * @returns {Boolean}
         */
        isAllowed: function () {
            return columnStatusValidator.isValid(this.source(), 'brand', 'show_attributes');
        }
    });
});
```

proj/app/code/MyVendor/Product/view/base/web/template/product/brand.html

```html
<strong if="isAllowed()"
        class="product-item-brand">
    <a attr="href: $row().url" html="$col.getLabel($row())"/>
</strong>
```

and it even renders the HTML but without brand(custom attribute) value

[image]

how can I make this thing works? (render the value of the custom attribute, should I dig around data provider?)

Appreciate for any help

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should use a data provider.

You can find solution on [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/278142/magento-2-add-new-attribute-delivery-time-to-recently-viewed-widget) page.